# How to label Knob within the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I would like to know how to include a text also inside the value field provided in the knob.js plugin.

https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob

I did not come across a parameter where I can include text field also inside the value. If there is a work around please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a 'format' hook to change the way that the text value is formatted before it gets displayed.

For example to add a percentage sign to the text you could do something like:

```
$(".dial").knob({
  'format' : function (value) {
     return value + '%';
  }
});
```

The `value` that gets passed in is the number, and whatever the function returns is what gets displayed.